# Finding instances where the earliest date/time value in Table A does not match a "Created" date/time from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I could use some help with a query to help me identify data missing from a table.  In my example, I have a history table missing the initial entry, usually created by a trigger from another table, but the trigger was turned off.  This table - we will call Table B - contains a DateTimeChanged and a DateTimeCreated column.  The DateTimeChanged and DateTimeCreated columns should be equal on the initial entry to the table.  However, since this trigger was off, I am missing an entry for a specific period.

I aim to identify instances where the *earliest DateTimeChanged* for each group of records does not match the DateTimeCreated value.  The earliest DateTimeChanged for each record should always be equal to the DateTimeCreated.  I can better determine my next steps by identifying where this is not true for my current data set.

Here is an example of the data:

Table A (Live)

| ID | Company | Created | Changed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | ABC123 | 2021-11-10 14:09:44.920 | 2022-05-19 11:13:17.137 |

Table B (History)

| ID | Company | Created | Changed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | ABC123 | 2021-11-10 14:09:44.920 | 2022-05-06 10:08:09.263 |
| 123456 | ABC123 | 2021-11-10 14:09:44.920 | 2022-05-19 11:13:17.137 |

In Table B, there is a missing row where the Created and Changed date should be the same.  This is because a new line should be created in Table B upon any insert, update, or deletion from Table A, but the trigger was disabled.

How can I find all instances where the earliest record in Table B does not have a row with a DateTimeChanged equal to the DateTimeCreated in Table A for my ID and Company combination?  I believe I would have to use the min(DateTimeChanged) in Table B to compare against the DateTimeCreated in Table A.  But I have yet to find an effective way to do this for each ID and Company combination I have.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

### To INSERT missing rows from Table A into Table B:

*Sync B with A - Add Existent A Rows to B*

You can perform a `JOIN` from `Table A` to `Table B`, then `GROUP BY` your columns `HAVING` `MAX` Changed Date in `Table A` > `MAX` Changed Date in `Table B`.

**To SELECT:**

```
   SELECT A.ID, A.Company, A.Created, A.Changed 
   FROM TableA A
   INNER JOIN TableB B
   ON A.ID = B.ID AND A.Company = B.Company
   GROUP BY A.ID, A.Company, A.Created, A.Changed 
   HAVING MAX(A.Changed) > MAX(B.Changed)
```

**To INSERT:**

```
INSERT INTO TableB (ID, Company, Created, Changed)
SELECT A.ID, A.Company, A.Created, A.Changed 
FROM TableA A
INNER JOIN TableB B
ON A.ID = B.ID AND A.Company = B.Company
GROUP BY A.ID, A.Company, A.Created, A.Changed 
HAVING MAX(A.Changed) > MAX(B.Changed)
```

See [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=dddf68ee869929cf60db3afc3d82777a).

---

*On the flip side:*

---

### To DELETE unmatched rows from Table A in Table B:

*Sync A with B - Removing Non-Existent A Rows from B*

You can perform a `JOIN` from `Table B` to `Table A`, then `GROUP BY` your columns `HAVING` `MIN` Changed Date in `Table B` < `MIN` Changed Date in `Table A`.

**To SELECT:**

```
SELECT B.ID, B.Company, B.Created, B.Changed 
FROM TableB B
INNER JOIN TableA A 
ON A.ID = B.ID AND A.Company = B.Company
GROUP BY B.ID, B.Company, B.Created, B.Changed 
HAVING MIN(B.Changed) < MIN(A.Changed)
```

**To DELETE:**

**Note**, for the `DELETE`, you need `JOIN` by **all** columns to essentially create a key to `JOIN` on since you don't have a `UNIQUE` primary key constraint on `Table B`, being that its a historical table.

```
DELETE C
  FROM TableB C
JOIN
(
  SELECT B.ID, B.Company, B.Created, B.Changed 
  FROM TableB B
  INNER JOIN TableA A 
  ON A.ID = B.ID AND A.Company = B.Company
  GROUP BY B.ID, B.Company, B.Created, B.Changed 
  HAVING MIN(B.Changed) < MIN(A.Changed) 
) D ON C.ID = D.ID AND C.Company = D.Company 
AND C.Created = D.Created AND C.Changed = D.Change
```

See [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2e587f962f3c0b01c5d93602b5f11891).